# BaseHTTPServer not recognizing CSS files

Tags: python

I'm writing a pretty basic webserver (well, trying) and while it's now serving HTML fine, my CSS files don't seem to be recognized at all.  I have Apache2 running on my machine as well, and when I copy my files to the docroot, the pages are served correctly.  I've also checked permissions and they seems to be fine.  Here's the code I have so far:

```
class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
     def do_GET(self):
           try:
                if self.path == "/":
                     self.path = "/index.html"
                if self.path == "favico.ico":
                     return
                if self.path.endswith(".html"):
                     f = open(curdir+sep+self.path)
                     self.send_response(200)
                     self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
                     self.end_headers()
                     self.wfile.write(f.read())
                     f.close()
                     return
                return
            except IOError:
                self.send_error(404)
      def do_POST(self):
            ...
```

Is there anything special I need to be doing in order to serve CSS files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could add this to your if clause

```
            elif self.path.endswith(".css"):
                 f = open(curdir+sep+self.path)
                 self.send_response(200)
                 self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/css')
                 self.end_headers()
                 self.wfile.write(f.read())
                 f.close()
                 return
```

Alternatively

```
import os
from mimetypes import types_map
class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
       try:
            if self.path == "/":
                 self.path = "/index.html"
            if self.path == "favico.ico":
                 return
            fname,ext = os.path.splitext(self.path)
            if ext in (".html", ".css"):
                 with open(os.path.join(curdir,self.path)) as f:
                     self.send_response(200)
                     self.send_header('Content-type', types_map[ext])
                     self.end_headers()
                     self.wfile.write(f.read())
            return
        except IOError:
            self.send_error(404)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I figured it was something like this, but wasn't sure if I needed a separate case.  Added this and it worked like a charm!

Comment: This was very instructive code for me -- thanks, gnibbler.  One minor note: in python 2.7 at least, it's mimetypes.types_map (plural), not .type_map

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a case that handles css files. Try changing:

```
if self.path.endswith(".html") or self.path.endswith(".css"):
```

Comment: Well, you'll probably want to add it as a separate case -- you'll want to set the Content-Type differently for CSS. But this should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I ended up adding a separate case and it worked like a charm.