# Python BaseHTTPRequestHandler css loaded but not rendered

Tags: python, html, css, basehttprequesthandler

I'm stumped. The below code will return the index.html as well as the css asked for, but when the index.html is requested by Firefox, it won't render the page with the css applied. I have the same result in Konqueror (which in Chrome based)

```
class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if (self.path.endswith("/")):
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
            self.end_headers()
            with open('index.html', 'r') as file:
                template = file.read()
            self.wfile.write(bytes(eval_template(template, env).encode("utf-16")))
        
        elif (self.path.endswith(".css")):
            with open(os.path.join('.', self.path[1:]), 'rb') as file:
                response = file.read()
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/css")
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(response)
```

The css is referenced in the index.html in this manner:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

When I look in the developer console, I can verify that the request for style.css file went without issue (200 OK).

When I open the file with Firefox as a file, it sees the css as well in the same directory and renders the file with the css as intended, so I'm inclined to think my code above is missing something.

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: Try affixing something to the end of the css filename, e.g. `href="style.css?xyz"`. If that resolves the issue it means the css file was stuck in the cache. For a permanent solution, affix something to it dynamically, such as the time, while in development.

Comment: Didn't help. Also, if a cached css was applied, I would as least expect to see its effects.

Comment: "When I open the file with Firefox as a file, it sees the css as well in the same directory and renders the file with the css as intended" ... where then are you having a problem?

Comment: When I run the code above and point my browsers to it, via http://localhost:8080.

Comment: Why do you write the css to the pipe differently from the html? I'm just curious, i'm not questioning your approach. Regarding these `self.wfile.write()`

Comment: At first I had it in the same way, got this problem, then I tried this. It didn't make a difference. The html is in utf-16, but the css is in utf-8. Also, I have a simple templating system for html but not for css.

Comment: See this SO post. Might be exactly what you need even though its kinda old. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291120/basehttpserver-not-recognizing-css-files

Answer (score 0):

After GetSet pointed me in the right direction, it appeared changing the css write line to:

```
self.wfile.write(bytes(response))
```

solve the problem.